# Getting Results Back To Main From BackgroundWorker onPostExecute

Tags: android

Sorry for asking this but I recently started develop android and new to Java.

Currently I am able to "Toast" onPostExecute results in "BackgroundWorkerLocation.java". What I need is to somehow pass these results back to "MainActivty.java" from where I execute this class.

MainActivity.java

```
    String type = "get_location";
    String tLatitude = String.valueOf(latitude);
    String tLongitude = String.valueOf(longitude);
    BackgroundWorkerLocation backgroundWorkerLocation = new BackgroundWorkerLocation(getApplicationContext());
    backgroundWorkerLocation.execute(type, tLatitude, tLongitude);

    // I need "Results" here
```

BackgroundWorkerLocation.java

```
public class BackgroundWorkerLocation extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

Context context;

BackgroundWorkerLocation(Context ctx){
    context = ctx;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // Some background work
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // Currently I am able to Toast "RESULT" here
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
}
```

Comment: Create an Interface , lets say `ICallBack`. define a method `onComplete` in here. Implement this in your` MainActivity.java` which will be your call back method after service is complete. When you call your service, pass instance of `MainActivity.java` in your service . `OnPostExecute`, you call onComplete method of main. You can also achieve this by LocalBroadCastManager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create an interface that you can use as a callback:

```
 interface MyCallback {
      void onResult(String result);
 }
```

In your activity you create an anonymous implementation of this callback.
Pass it into your ASyncTask.

```
String type = "get_location";
String tLatitude = String.valueOf(latitude);
String tLongitude = String.valueOf(longitude);
BackgroundWorkerLocation backgroundWorkerLocation = new BackgroundWorkerLocation(getApplicationContext(), new MyCallback() {
 @Override
 public void onResult(String result) {
       // I need "Results" here
 }
});
backgroundWorkerLocation.execute(type, tLatitude, tLongitude);
```

When the ASyncTask completes, you call the "onResult" method of the callback.

```
public class BackgroundWorkerLocation extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

Context context;
private final MyCallback myCallback;

BackgroundWorkerLocation(Context ctx, MyCallback myCallback){
    context = ctx;
    this.myCallback = myCallback;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // Some background work
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // Currently I am able to Toast "RESULT" here
    myCallback.onResult(result);
}

}
```

This is how you can share data between two classes.

Note that because the callback implementation is anonymous, it has a reference to your Activity, therefore if your task lives longer than your activity it can cause a memory leak. (your next problem :-))

Comment: Thanks. You are a saviour.